# When to use IdentityServer 3 for OAuth

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, identityserver4, identityserver3

I am new to Identitysever3 but I have worked with OAuth and OpenId.

I need to create a MVC client that will interact with QBO (Quickbooks Online). QBO uses OAuth by it's own.To start with I followed the github sample project from QBO community to use QBO REST API. This MVC app has OAuth stuff in MVC controller.

Now I need to create actual MVC project that will interact with QBO. I am after best practices to authorize my project. Here my authorize server would be QBO. So is my app is the right candidate to use Identityserver3?

My understanding is that I need to add Identityserver 3 project in my solution and use authorize server URI, client Id and client secret provided by QBO.

I assume Identityserver 3 is a framework that is the best way to use OAuth and OpenID connect as a separate project so it can be reused in other solutions. AND it's not an Authorization server, am I correct?

waiting for help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume Identityserver 3 is a framework that is the best way to use OAuth and OpenID connect as a separate project so it can be reused in other solutions. AND it's not an Authorization server.

This statement is **not** correct. In fact IdentityServer3 implements OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect and is an authorization server. If you have QBO as authorization server, you don't need to use identityserver3.

what you need is a client for OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect. You can use [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) which is implemented by the same team that implements IdentityServer3.

Comment: Thanks it clears my confusion. QBO has it's own client that DiscoveryClient so I don't need IdentityModel either. 

So is it possible to have one project for Open Authorization that will connect to different authorize servers so we can reuse that?

Comment: You are right, If it has its own client, then there's no need to use IdentityModel.

Comment: So is it possible to have one project for Open Authorization that will connect to different authorize servers so we can reuse that?

Comment: Yes authorization servers can use each other as external Identity provider. Let me ask you this question, do you want to have your own project and API? But you want to authenticate your users with QBO?

Comment: Yes my MVC client will connect to QBO and authorize users with QBO and get access token. Then interact with QBO REST API by sending access token.

Comment: If QBO, Peach tree and other software that you are using all are implemented OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect protocols you can use Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect package for all of them